# How to setup a virtual host in Ubuntu?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, virtualhost

I have an app that's accessible `via 1.2.3.4/myapp`. The app is installed in `/var/www/myapp`. I've set up a subdomain(`apps.mydomain.com`) that points to `1.2.3.4`. I want the server to point to `var/www/myapp` if I type `apps.mydomain.com/myapp`, how do I do that? I have experience creating virtual hosts(lots of them) locally but I'm lost because it's now in production and it's a little different. Here's my virtual host config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName apps.mydomain.com/myapp

        DocumentRoot /var/www/myapp/public
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride All
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Any idea why I still see the files instead of pointing me to the document root?

Just in case someone might ask, the app is based on Laravel 4 framework. It's really bad right now because anyone can access the files from the browser.

Comment: Really...this question has nothing to do with EC2. We like to keep tags "clean", and as stated in the edit comment, this issue you're having has *nothing* to do with the fact that you're running on EC2. It's a generic linux/apache problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one.

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName apps.mydomain.com

```
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
    Alias /myapp "/var/www/myapp/public/"
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride All
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

And if you don't want others to access apps.mydomain.com, add a index.php in /var/www with a redirect to apps.mydomain.com/myapp.

```
<?php
    header("Location: /myapp");
?>
```

I think it will work as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

I think that adding this to the virtualhost of apps.mydomain.com should work:

`Alias /myapp "/var/www/myapp/public/"`

This should point apps.mydomain.com/myapp to that folder﻿

And if that works you can remove existing virtual host of `apps.mydomain.com/myapp`

But i'm not a server admin, I can be wrong. Just wait it out :)﻿

Comment: It didn't work. Thanks a lot anyway man :-)